# Has a super being like Thor or an X-Man used the Ant-Man suit?

Tags: marvel, ant-man

Obviously there is nothing like this in any of the movies as of yet, but in the comics, are there any instances of a super-being putting on the Ant-Man suit and shrinking down and using their powers while being as small as an ant?

Comment: Imagine if the Hulk wore one...

Comment: @thegreatjedi, yeah, I was wondering that, but since the Hulk increases in size, he would break the suit before he could be shrunk.

Comment: I can't find any instances, I'm pretty sure that only regular humans have ever worn the suit itself, and Pym Discs don't exist in Earth-616, so unless they explore this topic in one of the movies, I'm not sure we'll ever get to see a mini Hulk, awesome though that would be.

Comment: Although he wasn't wearing the suit, Hulk has shrunk due to Pym's science in the comics. That's how he meets Jarella, his microscopic lover.

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_140, http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_154

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if Psyklop was using Pym's stuff in Avengers 88 (leading to Hulk 140), but it was a potion from Pym's laboratory that led to Hulk shrinking in Hulk 154

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of the All-New Wolverine issues (#5), X-23 wears an ant man suit.
Given that she is a mutant with claws, enhanced healing, strength, senses and reflexes, I think she fairly easily counts as a super-being.

> She does this alongside Janet Van Dyne (Wasp) to fight nanites infecting one of her clones.